# Use an Arduino Mega in a incubator (high humidity)

Tags: arduino-mega

I wonder whether it is possible to use an Arduino Mega in a cell incubator.

In the incubator there is a temperature of 37°C, 5% CO2 in the atmosphere and a high relative humidity of around 95% - 98%. I think the temperature (specs of ATmega2560, temperature range: -40 °C to 85 °C) and the CO2 is no problem.

But I am concerned the condensation due to the high humidity will cause damage.

One mitigation could be, that I first pre-warm the Arduino Mega so it doesn't condensate.

(There is a possibility that I don't put the Arduino in the incubator at all, but it would be easier if I could).

Comment: The condensation is a real problem. Don't put an Arduino Mega inside an incubator. Why use such a big board? Perhaps a smaller board that can be potted in something might work, but perhaps others know about that.

Comment: Put the mega in a ziplock bag. Only have the wires stick out.

Comment: You could try a DIY conformal coating spray, read the label to see if it will do what you want.  If you have the budget then there are companies that will do a proper job, but it won't be cheep.  I would also worry about the temp.  You will need to make sure you can dissipate the heat from the board quickly and without messing up the temp of you incubator.

Comment: Why would it be so much easier to put it in the incubator?

Comment: I did the same this 2 years ago and had problems with co2 sensor mostly.
Which one do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"-40 °C to 85 °C" for the processor, yes, for the other parts, who knows?

The board doesn't get that hot unless you are powering from like a 12V source, and then it's just the regulator that gets hot.

You could a [spray-on conformal coat](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/MG-Chemicals/422B-340G?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvJqaFk9BIiv7PGWcg%252b8l58Olg6eeFJn18%3d), Mouser.com carries them. Insert any wires into the headers you will use and cover any headers you may want to use before you spray, if you get coating down into the female headers you may have poor contact later on.

The ziplock bag idea sounds like a good start as a start, put some silicon along the seal to fill the holes where the zipper won't close right next to the wires.